# Refresh Component on Record Save

Tags: lightning-aura-components, refresh

I have a lightning component on a record page that I want to refresh when the record is saved. How do I do this? Here is my Code:

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="DaytoBegin" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">

<aura:attribute name="ifmsrc" type="String"/>
<iframe id="frmprcrequest1" height="125px" src="{!v.ifmsrc}" frameborder="false" style="width:100%" />
```

Helper:

```
({
    buildComponents : function(cmp) {      
        var number = cmp.get("v.number");
        var oppid = cmp.get("v.recordId");
        $A.log(oppid);        
        cmp.set("v.ifmsrc", oppid);}    
}})
```

Renderer:

```
({
    render: function(cmp, helper) {        
        var ret = cmp.superRender(); 
        helper.buildComponents(cmp);
        return ret; 
    },

    rerender: function(cmp, helper) {
        helper.buildComponents(cmp);
    }
})
```

Controller.js:

```
({
    refresh : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = cmp.get('c.AssignValue');        
        action.setCallback(cmp,
                           function(response) {
                               var state = response.getState();
                               if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
                                   $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();                                   
                               } else {
                                   console.log('Error')
                               }
                           });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);        
    }    
})
```

Added the refresh function and now I'm getting CMP not defined?

Answer (score 1):

[force:refreshView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm) is used to refresh the view when you need to get new data. Something like this:

```
$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
```

Comment: When I add that to my controller I get errors or it freezes during the refresh

Comment: This refreshes only the record page where the Component is hosted, you need to manually handle the refresh of your component

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if you are in `LEX` or `SF1` - which will handle handle the `refreshView` event for you and refresh the component.

If you are in lightning out, hosted by a VisualForce page for example, this event will return `null`, hence you get the `component not defined` error.

Try this:

```
var evt = $A.get('e.force:refreshView');
if (evt){
  evt.fire();
}
else {
  helper.buildComponents(); 
}
```